# Information downloaded from a combat spacesuit's logs tell about a soldiers multiple combat drops

Tags: story-identification

I hope I am not confusing two different stories, but as I remember it the story revolves around a soldier who's entire unit is destroyed except him.  He ends up being scheduled for combat drops over and over when the average soldier only survives a handful.

The story is told as the combat logs downloaded from his spacesuit that is found later.  That's about all I remember other than it had something of a Starship Troopers feel to it.

Comment: The part of the soldier surviving longer than anyone else makes me think of [The Forever War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Forever_War) by [Joe Haldeman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Haldeman), but the combat log bit doesn't match.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like [John Steakley's Armor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armor_%28novel%29).

It's an exact match for the "everyone but him dies, and a glitch schedules him for every combat sortie" point.

It's not so much combat logs as some sort of memory of the suit and they're reliving, though.

Comment: Was his number of combat drops a glitch or a deliberate punishment for refusing promotion to be an officer?

Comment: @erdiede The way I remember it being explained, it was a glitch in the system because it filed everyone in the group he was in as dead. When he was discharged, they cut the number of deployments he was credited with from something like 20 to 6 (the usual being more like 2).

Comment: If he was discharged why was his suit of armor on the same planet he was on? I think the military would have kept that. If I remember right he was a deserter (from multiple responsibilities ;) ). I also thought his mission count got reset because of something related to his treatment in the medical facilities, a doctor couldn't believe how many times he had been treated (to the point where their fancy-smancy futuristic drugs stopped working) and after digging into his mission count someone decides to reset it. Desertion ensues. It's been a while, I could be wrong.

Comment: This looks very familiar, looks like I am going to have to give it a read and see if it is the one.

Comment: Just got done with the re-read.  I must have read this well over 20 years ago, so while my memory of things wasn't perfect, this definitely had to be the book.  Sorry for the long time before responding.  Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Could it be one of the books in John Scalzi's *Old Man's War* series? The books share some of the feel of *Starship Troopers* or *The Forever War*, although I'm not sure the structure of the story as you remember it fits with any of the books.

Comment: I don't think it's the Old Man's War series. I've read the first two books, and looked at the descriptions of the rest. None of them match up with the OP's descriptions.

Comment: Having read both of these books it all sounds familiar, but definitely not Starship Troopers which is a great book itself.